# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol] in PHP Laravel on macOS using Brew

Tags: php, sql-server, openssl, odbc

I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect to a SQL Server database using PHP Laravel on macOS with Brew. I'm receiving the following error message:
`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol]`

1. Checked this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1462, but it didn't resolve my problem.
2. Switched from OpenSSL version 3 to OpenSSL version 1.1, which led to a different error.

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to establish a successful connection to the SQL Server. Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this SSL protocol error and connect to the database successfully?

- Operating System: macOS M1 Chip
- Package Manager: Brew
- PHP Framework: Laravel @9.x
- PHP: https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php @8.2 (with pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv extention) This error encountered after `brew update` as i remember

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: TLS support in SQL Server depends on both the specific version of SQL and the version of windows.  what is the exact version of sql server:  SELECT @@VERSION. What OS is SQL server running on (e.g. windows server 2016)?